# Using TStringList in class definition

Tags: class, delphi, tstringlist

I'm doing a simple class definition in Delphi and I wanted to use a `TStringList` in the class and its constructor (so everytime you create an object, you pass it a `StringList` and it does some magic stuff to the `StringList` data, copying the string list to its own internal string list).

The problem I get is that when I try to declare what it "uses" before the class definition (so it knows how to handle the `TStringList`), it fails on compile.  But without that, it doesn't know what a `TStringList` is.  So it seems to be a scoping issue.

Below is a (very simplified) class definition, similar to what I'm trying to do.  Can someone suggest how I can make this work and get the scoping right?

I tried adding the `uses` statements at the project level as well, but it still fails.  I wonder what I need to do to get this right.

```
unit Unit_ListManager;

interface

type
TListManager = Class

private
  lmList   : TStringList;
  procedure SetList;


published
  constructor Create(AList : TStringList);
end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils,
  StrUtils,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

  constructor TBOMManager.Create(AList : TStringList);
  begin
    lmList := TStringList.Create;
    lmList := AListList;
  end;

  procedure SetPartsList(AList : TStringList);
  begin
     lmList := AListList;
     ShowMessage('Woo hoo, got here...');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Don't forget the `inherited` statement in the constructor.

Comment: @LURD is that even necessary when no parent type is defined?

Comment: @LaKraven, strictly no, but hard to find errors can arise as soon as the base class is changed. I would not allow this in my codebase.

Comment: @LURD that's a good point... I'll update my answer to account for that possibility :)

Comment: If you don't want to have only a reference to the external Stringlist(that's what I understood from your create) you must not use `lmList := AListList;` but `assign` e.g. `constructor TListManager.Create(AList: TStringList);
begin
   inherited Create;
   FlmList := TStringList.Create;
   SetList(AList);
end;

procedure TListManager.SetList(AList : TStringList);
begin
   FlmList.Assign(AList);
end;`

Comment: Disagree with the -1 so... +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show where exactly you were adding the unit reference, but I'm betting it was the wrong place. Take note of the additional code between `interface` and `type`.

I've also corrected your definition of the `constructor`, which you had placed in `published` instead of `public`. Only `property` items belong in the `published` section.

```
unit Unit_ListManager;

interface

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  StrUtils,
  Vcl.Dialogs;    

type
TListManager = Class
private
  lmList   : TStringList;
  procedure SetList;    
public
  constructor Create(AList : TStringList);
end;

implementation

constructor TListManager.Create(AList : TStringList);
begin
  inherited Create; // This way, if the parent class changes, we're covered!
  // lmList := TStringList.Create; This would produce a memory leak!
  lmList := AListList;
end;

procedure TListManager.SetList;
begin
// You never provided an implementation for this method
end;

end.
```

Comment: Umm, this seems to reproduce the inconsistency in the constructor (TListManager v. TBOMManager) in the OP's q.

Comment: @MartynA I missed that one... thanks for pointing it out, I've corrected it now :)

Comment: Ahh thank you!  There was some renaming I had done when I copied what I was working on.  That explains List v BOM manager.  You are right, I had that scoping wrong.  Thanks for the help with this, it compiles now!

Comment: In the future, @DoubleE, it is very helpful if you post the content of the warning/error messages in with your question... this makes it easier for us to rapidly locate the problem and provide a solution :)
Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: this: `lmList := TStringList.Create; lmList := AListList;` does not make much sense ;-). Maybe he is searching for assign ....

Comment: You are leaking a stringlist. `lmList := AListList` will overwrite the internally created list.

Comment: `lmList.Text := AList.Text` will make a local copy if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: You probably want a destructor as well so you can free the stringlist.

Comment: Updated the answer to remove the silly memory leak (which, again, I didn't initially notice). No point in creating a fresh instance and having to manage that when passing a reference is sufficient!